# How to write select attributeA having n attributeB in relational algebra?

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I have a relation e.g. `R(Owner,Car)`. How can I return the owners who hold three cars in relational algebra? (and without using aggregate functions)

e.g. something like `σ(COUNT(Car)=3)(R)` but without using aggregate functions?

```
e.g.
given            return
+-+----+         +-+----+
|a|attX|         |a|attX|
+-+----+         +-+----+
|a|attY|   ==>   |a|attY|
+-+----+         +-+----+
|a|attZ|         |a|attZ|
+-+----+         +-+----+
|b|attX|
+-+----+
|c|attW|
+-+----+
|c|attX|
+-+----+
|c|attY|
+-+----+
|c|attZ|
+-+----+
```

Edit: Thanks for your answers, but I am looking for how to write this in relational algebra. This means in the form using operators like `σ`, `π`, `X`, `⋈`, and so on.

Comment: "without using aggregate functions" -- is that a stated requirement? Homework?

Comment: Yes, and yes. I have attempted this myself to no avail.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it, in SQL using operators that are easy to translate to relational algebra, and using slightly different test data (different types, same names):

```
WITH R 
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 1), 
                     (2, 2), (2, 3),
                     (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3),
                     (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)
             ) AS T (Owner, Car)
     ),
     OwnersWithAtLeastThreeCars
     AS
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT R1.Owner
        FROM R AS R1, R AS R2, R AS R3
       WHERE R1.Owner = R2.Owner
             AND R2.Owner = R3.Owner
             AND R1.Car <> R2.Car
             AND R1.Car <> R3.Car
             AND R2.Car <> R3.Car
     ),
     OwnersWithAtLeastFourCars
     AS
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT R1.Owner
        FROM R AS R1, R AS R2, R AS R3, R AS R4
       WHERE R1.Owner = R2.Owner
             AND R2.Owner = R3.Owner
             AND R3.Owner = R4.Owner
             AND R1.Car <> R2.Car
             AND R1.Car <> R3.Car
             AND R1.Car <> R4.Car
             AND R2.Car <> R3.Car
             AND R2.Car <> R4.Car
             AND R3.Car <> R4.Car
     )
SELECT * FROM OwnersWithAtLeastThreeCars
EXCEPT       
SELECT * FROM OwnersWithAtLeastFourCars;
```

---

p.s. I'm using 'old style' (i.e. pre-1992) standard SQL joins, which are widely condemned on Stackoverflow. I'm using them not only because it fits with the OP's list of available operators but, frankly, in these circumstances I find them much easier to write than using infix `INNER JOIN` notation.

Comment: Perfect answer in SQL. I managed to solve this myself and your answer corresponds nicely.

Answer (score 0):

you said σ(COUNT(Car)=3)(R), but COUNT is an aggregation function.

without aggregations, the only way I see is loop through the R table rows by row counting Owner. Something like:

```
for each row
    If owner=previous_owner then n_cars++ 
    else (if n_cars>=3 then return owner
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\pi_{Car.owner}(\sigma_{Car.owner = C1.owner\wedge 
                        C1.owner = C2.owner\wedge 
                        Car.vin != C1.vin\wedge 
                        C1.vin != C2.vin\wedge 
                        Car.vin != C2.vin}(Car x 
                                           \rho_{C1}(Car) x 
                                           \rho_{C2}(Car)))
 -
 \pi_{Car.owner}(\sigma_{Car.owner = C1.owner\wedge 
                        C1.owner = C2.owner\wedge 
                        C2.owner = C3.owner \wedge
                        Car.vin != C1.vin\wedge 
                        C1.vin != C2.vin\wedge 
                        Car.vin != C2.vin \wedge
                        Car.vin != C3.vin\wedge 
                        C1.vin != C3.vin\wedge 
                        C2.vin != C3.vin}(Car x 
                                           \rho_{C1}(Car) x 
                                           \rho_{C2}(Car) x
                                           \rho_{C3}(Car)))
```

where `\pi` is projection, `\sigma` is selection, `x` is cartesian product, `\rho` is renaming, `\wedge` represents conjunction and I assume the attributes of relation Car to be called `owner` and `vin`.